# What does >* do?

Tags: html, css, tags, media-queries

I encounter this several times, but i don't now what >* exactly is? I think it overwrites something, but i'm not sure.

```
.GridWrapper>* {
font-size: 14px
}

@media screen and (min-width:601px) {
.GridWrapper>* {
    font-size: 17px
}
}
```

Comment: Apply the rule for all direct child's of `.GridWrapper` element

Comment: I think it selcets all elements that have `.gridwrapper` as parent

Comment: Just note that it is a dirty way to accomplish the task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A > B` selector will select an element B that is a direct child of an element A; similar to `A B`, where it can be any descendant. `*` is any element. Thus, `.GridWrapper > *` means "all direct children of elements classed `GridWrapper`".

More on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors#Information.3A_Selectors_based_on_relationships).

Answer (score 1):

It simply means to select elements directly under the `class` GridWrapper to have a `font-size of 14px`.

Comment: @Morpheus - * asterisk is everything I believe.

Comment: Asterisk *is* everything. But `>` is not "inside", it is "directly under".

Comment: asterisk is everything, but not `>`

Comment: Point taken @Morpheus. Updated

Comment: @Amadan - `+` is "directly under". So `>` and `+` are the same?

Comment: I meant "under" as in hierarchy (DOM tree): in `A > B`, B is a child of A (but not grandchild, or further). In `A + B`, B is a *sibling* of A that comes after it *on the same level*. I did not mean literal under, just like an underling is not physically sat on by the upper management :)

Comment: Even I thought so .. That's why wanted to confirm - @Amadan